# Restoring an OLD iPhone backup

Tags: itunes, ios, backup, iphone

I recently made a full backup of my iPhone 4S to my computer. I was having some issues with it, so I went into DFU mode and did a clean install.

Unfortunately as soon as iTunes finished installing iOS 6, it automatically made a full back-up of my phone, and I now can't see the previous back-up I made. Please tell me it's still there!

How may I recover a previous back-up?

Comment: Pretty good question !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[I realize this is an older question and may not solve the problem for the OP, but this answer is intended to provide guidance to others.]

If you use iTunes backups, there is *only one backup (the latest) maintained per device at any point in time*. So in this case the new backup overwrote the older backup, and it would be possible to recover only if a copy of `~/Library/Application Support/MobileSync/Backup/` was made before the clean install (through Time Machine or any other solution), restoring that folder on the system and doing a restore from iTunes.

You can see the device backups (with the timestamps) available in iTunes by going to **iTunes** → **Preferences** and then navigating to the **Devices** tab.

Some recommendations and points to note to avoid such a situation and have something to fall back to:

- You can have multiple backups in iCloud for a device and choose which backup to restore from (assuming there are no device/iOS compatibility issues).
- Use both iCloud and iTunes backups together (once iCloud backup is turned on, automatic backups in iTunes would be turned off; so a manual backup would have to be triggered in iTunes).
- When using iTunes backup, trigger a manual backup in iTunes followed by a manual backup in Time Machine before major changes to a device, like re-installing iOS or jailbreaking or recovering from older backups.

See:
[Choosing an iOS backup method (Should I use iTunes or iCloud to back up my iOS device?)](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT5262)

Comment: Why was the older backup "corrupt"?

Comment: That was a misunderstanding of the problem. I've fixed it in the answer. Thanks.

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt : The older backup wasn't **corrupt** but was **overwritten** by the new one. This is a bad method from a security standpoint but at the same time avoid a huge space waste.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have older backups:

Mac OS: `~/Library/Application Support/MobileSync/Backup`

Windows XP: `%AppData%\Apple Computer\MobileSync\Backup`

Windows Vista: `%AppData%\Roaming\Apple Computer\MobileSync\Backup`

Windows 7: `%AppData%\Roaming\Apple Computer\MobileSync\Backup`

Go onto iTunes, right click on your device on the left-hand side bar, and their should be an option 'Restore From Backup', or something similar, click that and it'll restore your iPhone to a previous backup.

Answer (score -3):

You can see all backups in Itunes settings -> backup
I think it keeps two or three latest backups

Comment: The OP says he can't

Comment: The OP ? What's that ?

Comment: Original Poster a term in usenet and other fora for the first one to start a thread

Answer (score -3):

If you have back up your iPhone data, you can restore from the backup.

To restore information from a backup, use one of the following methods after connecting your iOS device to the computer with which you normally sync:

Right-click (or Control-click) the device and choose Restore from Backup
If you have a new phone, you can connect to iTunes and it will prompt to restore from your backup Solution from Apple.com: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1766

Comment: The OP says the backup is bad - how do you get an OLD backup