# How to restore previous iPhone backups (not the latest one)

Tags: iphone, backup, restore

I messed up with my contacts a bit on iPhone 5 and then did not do the smartest thing — connected it to the computer and it backed up, erasing all previous contacts from the computer too.

However, in `\AppData\Roaming\Apple Computer\MobileSync\Backup` folder (Win7) there are some previous backups for my iPhone (from November, October, etc.), which hopefully contain the contacts.

iTunes does not see the earlier backups, only the latest one.  Although all the files are together in the iPhone backup subfolder with long gibberish name.  Neither other recovery soft can see the previous backups.

My guess is that `Info.plist, Status.plist` and similar files are responsible for that.

How can I backup from previous backup files and not from the latest? Do Info.plist, Status.plist, etc. have to be changed / deleted?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: try this http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/104865/46541

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to cover some details of my case.  I don't have a Time Machine, I have Win7 on a PC.  And there is only one folder with a number of files.  Maybe contacts are stored in some particular file, which I could check specifically?