# How to recover Old BackUp?

Tags: iphone, itunes

I recently made a full backup of my iPhone 7 to my computer a day back. I was adding some new songs in Itunes then I connected the Phone to those songs.

Unfortunately as soon as Iphone connected to iTunes, it automatically made a full back-up of my phone, and I now can't see the previous back-up I made. Please tell me!

How to recover that Old BackUp.

Comment: I think you question is already answered here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/94983/restoring-an-old-iphone-backup#104865

Answer (score 1):

iTunes usually just updates the previous backup as part of its incremental backup process. But you can look in the iTunes Preferences ->  Devices tab to see all of the backups iTunes sees to make sure:

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204215

To make extra sure that there's not a partial or broken backup that iTunes isn't seeing, you can also go look in the folder for the backups. Here's an article I wrote with instructions for getting to the iTunes backups folder on different OSes:

https://deciphertools.com/blog/where-are-iphone-backups/