# iTunes: How to find backup corresponding to a particular version of iOS?

Tags: ios, itunes, restore

I have an iPhone 8 Plus, which I upgraded to iOS 12.3.2. iOS 12.3.2 was a special bug fix release which is available only for iPhone 8 Plus models.

I want to downgrade it to iOS 12.3.1, but I think I already did an iTunes backup for iOS 12.3.2.

How can I find a backup in iTunes which can be restored to iOS 12.3.1?

Comment: It's not really a dupe, though the info that "iTunes only saves one backup" is quite relevant.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Restoring an OLD iPhone backup](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/94983/restoring-an-old-iphone-backup)

Answer (score 1):

If you have an old 12.3.1 backup of your iPhone, you can restore your iphone from that backup.

Then you have to delete (or drag outside the folder) your 12.3.2 backup so that iTunes restore your device from the new "latest one".

from [Apple support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204215) :

**Find iOS backups on your Mac**

Find a list of your backups:

1. Click Search icon in the menu bar.
2. Type or copy and paste this: `~/Library/Application Support/MobileSync/Backup/`
3. Press Return.

OR

Locate a specific backup:

1. Open iTunes. Click iTunes in the menu bar, then choose Preferences.
2. Click Devices.
3. Control-click the backup that you want, then choose Show in Finder.
   [image]

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBktz.png I don't see version-wise folder structure. There are tens of folders in the last one. Question is unclear too. So please hold up. Also use `code` format in 2.)

Comment: hmm, I was just copying the Apple support page. Didn´t knew that bakcup folder was so messy ! There is also another way via iTunes. I don't think the question is unclear though, he wants to know where an older backup should be found (if it exist)

Comment: I bet this is for multiple iPhones(or either backup was archived.). I see only one item in the list and it too leads to the same folder. Yes, the location is clear. Where is the version?

Comment: Assuming michael here only have one backup from 12.3.2, the other one should be 12.3.1 (or older). But yeah, this do not show the version of backup...

Comment: iTunes only saves the last backup. Anything earlier would have to be recovered from Time Machine.

Comment: @Tetsujin really ? Then why Apple shows a picture of 2 separate john´s backup on the support page ? nonsense of them... But I do remember cleaning few older backup via CleanMyMac to free space (and I never use time machine)...

Comment: Different devices, different entries in that list. I guess "John" wasn't too smart in naming his devices;) Mine shows 2 phones & a pad [all properly named to identify], which is what I have. No backup == no recovery.

Comment: @Tetsujin I hope you're not disregarding the possibility of archived backup in order to show multiple entries. I don't know how it would look like. I might be wrong  but it made sense. Blogs didn't provide a screenshot.

Comment: @ankiiiiiii - I've never tried, sorry. I've no idea how it would look or respond if one were present.

Answer (score 1):

If you use iTunes to back up multiple times, in general, the new backup will overwrite the old one. Only third-party tools will back up multiple copies.

When you view backup of a device in iTunes, you can right-click on the backup then click show in finder. You should find an `Info.plist` file. It contains a string named Product Version after the entries for applications ends. Hitting the Space-bar should reveal the contents of the file, open it in TextEdit to search for the Product Version.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Where might this be? How would you find it or open it or know how to recognise the data within it?

Comment: @tessujin I assume he knows how to find the backup folder, I added the answer.

Comment: You can't assume anything. A good answer is a complete answer.